# QGIS .dxf file conversion to .kml no geometry notification

Tags: qgis-3, kml, dxf, layer-to-kml

My colleague is having an issue converting DXF files into KML files.
He is using QGIS version Lima (not sure version no.) and I am using Hannover (3.16)

We have checked all the various options and plugins but when he loads (import dxf layers) then tries to save layer as a KML he gets an error after filling in the KML details advising there's no geometry. {See below for error}.

The DXF file shows a route on the main window when he loads it. (the file just contains a few polylines in a route from point A to point B.)
DXF file is in ESPG-27700 (and as on the project) and output on the KML is set to EPSG-4326.

I can take the same DXF on my version and although it doesn't show the DXF when loaded, the KML output works fine and checking on Google Earth shows the correct output.

[image: no geometry error message]

Does anyone have any ideas of whether this is setting somewhere or something that may be different in the versions that would make it not work as I have followed exactly the same process on both myself, and cannot for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

edit- I don't have enough reputation to add a comment but unfortunately the file is a company one so legally cannot be shared.

Comment: is the original .dxf file shareable?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "KML Tools" plug-in, it does a great job exporting data into KML/KMZ:

[image]

[image]

[image]